# Spring boot / spring security / keycloak classloader problems

Tags: spring-boot, grails, spring-security, classloader, keycloak

I have added keycloak integration to an existing Grails 3 (3.3.2) application, and for the most part it is working well.  However, I sporadically get ClassCastExceptions or GroovyCastExceptions trying to cast class Foo to class Foo.

I understand that the two common causes of this are duplicate inclusions of the class or multiple loads of the class into different classloaders.  I have confirmed via extensive inspection (heap dump, and -class:verbose log review) that the classes in question not only exist only once per application but are loaded only once per application as well.  Specifically, for the X applications I have running, the class in question is loaded exactly X times, each time by a different WebappClassloader.

One complicating factor is that I am running multiple applications (compiled to wars via `gradle war`) within the same Tomcat instance.  Each application includes a copy of the jar where the offending classes are found.  My understanding is that tomcat's classloader hierarchy should allow this without problems.

Stacktraces and build config follow.  Does anyone have a suggestion for how to troubleshoot this further?

*build.gradle*

```
// relevant parts:
dependencies {
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
    compile "org.grails:grails-core"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    provided "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    compile "org.grails:grails-dependencies"
    compile "org.grails:grails-web-boot"
    compile "org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:4.2.3.RELEASE"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:1.5.8.RELEASE"
    compile "org.keycloak:keycloak-spring-security-adapter:3.4.3.Final"
}
```

*Exceptions (truncated)*

```
2019-03-14 13:42:39.396 [http-apr-8443-exec-3] ERROR o.s.b.w.s.ErrorPageFilter Forwarding to error page from request [/service/search/config] due to exception [org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequest cannot be cast to org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequest]
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequest cannot be cast to org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequest
        at org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequest.lookup(GrailsWebRequest.java:435)
        at org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequest.inheritEncodingStateRegistry(GrailsWebRequest.java:127)
        at org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequest.<init>(GrailsWebRequest.java:108)
```

and

```
2019-03-14 16:06:50.938 [pool-54-thread-1] ERROR StackTrace Full Stack Trace:
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'MimeType { name=*/*,extension=all,parameters=[q:1.0] }' with class 'grails.web.mime.MimeType' to class 'grails.web.mime.MimeType'
    at org.grails.web.mime.HttpServletResponseExtension.getMimeTypesInternal(HttpServletResponseExtension.groovy:232)
    at org.grails.web.mime.HttpServletResponseExtension.getMimeTypeForRequest(HttpServletResponseExtension.groovy:147)
    at org.grails.web.mime.HttpServletResponseExtension.getMimeType(HttpServletResponseExtension.groovy:118)
    at org.grails.web.mime.DefaultMimeTypeResolver.resolveResponseMimeType(DefaultMimeTypeResolver.groovy:41)
```

Comment: A common feature of places that throw these exceptions is that (so far) they are always `(Foo) request.getAttribute(whatever)`...not sure if this is related or just a common place to perform class casting in grails.

Comment: Could it be that the sessions get somehow mixed up if a user switches from one webapp to another?

Comment: I don't believe that classes would be loaded per-session, but regardless this is happening for me as a single user with no one else signed in (development server).

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Unfortunately no; we ended up moving to a non-keycloak solution for other reasons and so this was never resolved.